# How to write a native Mac OS X GUI with Rust?

Tags: macos, rust

I'm going to write a software using Rust:

- core written in Rust
- native Mac OS GUI written in Rust (preferably) or other language

Which setup allows that? Is it possible at all?

P.S. I never programmed nor with Rust nor with Cocoa/etc before.

Comment: https://github.com/servo/rust-cocoa

Answer (score 10):

GUIs designed in Interface Builder work best if you use bindings, but bindings assume Objective-C. For this reason I'm writing GUI part in Objective-C and core part in Rust.

The two can communicate via an [obj-c library](https://github.com/SSheldon/rust-objc) ([article about this](https://blog.bugsnag.com/building-macos-apps-with-rust/)), but the languages are quite different, so it's a bit awkward.

Rust can easily generate C-compatible static library which can be linked to an Objective-C program. You can even add Makefile target in Xcode to build the whole thing without leaving Xcode.

Comment: this sounds great! can you point to some examples, articles repositories? 
Thank you!